# elasticsearch: indexing & searching arabic text

Tags: elasticsearch

When I put the following things into elasticsearch-1.0.1 I expect the search queries to return the posts with id 200 and 201. But I get nothing returned. Hits:0.

What am I doing wrong? I'm searching exactly for what I put in, but get nothing out... (here's the test code for download: http://petoria.de/tmp/arabictest.sh).

But please keep in mind: I want to use the Arabic analyzer, because I want to develop my own analyzer later.

Best,
Koem

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/posts -d '{
  "settings" : {
    "number_of_shards" : 1
  }
}'

curl -XPOST localhost:9200/posts/post/_mapping -d '
{
  "post" : {
    "properties" : {
      "arabic_text" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "store" : true, "analyzer" : "arabic" },
      "english_text" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "store" : true, "analyzer" : "english" }
    }
  }
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/posts/post/200' -d '{
    "english_text" : "palestinian1",
    "arabic_text" : "فلسطينيه"
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/posts/post/201' -d '{
    "english_text" : "palestinian2",
    "arabic_text" : "الفلسطينية"
}'

search for palestinian1
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/posts/post/_search' -d '{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "analyzer" : "arabic",
            "query" : "فلسطينيه"
        }
    }
}'

search for palestinian2
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/posts/post/_search' -d '{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "analyzer" : "arabic",
            "query" : "الفلسطينية"
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: Did you ever made this work ?

Comment: Yes, IIRC the Content-Type did it. But if this doesn't work for you, I may have the code somewhere on my HD ...

Answer (score 3):

Just add the encoding to your URL, you can do it by specifying the "Content-Type" header as bellow:

```
Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
```